# How do I automatically make zip archives of every folder in a directory if the names are random?

Tags: windows, windows-11, 7-zip, gaming, archiving

I want to automatically save archives of Roblox versions. The Roblox versions folder path is "`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions`". It normally only has 2 folders: one for Roblox, and another for Roblox Studio.
The folders are named "version-" and then a bunch of random letters and numbers.

---

Each time Roblox updates, it deletes the old folder and makes a new one named "version-" and then a bunch of random letters and numbers. The names are the same for every person with the same version, it's just randomized before it gets put into an update. The current Roblox version I have is a folder named "`version-aa6e1ad459964fc3`". And the current Roblox Studio version I have is a folder named "`version-698262888e864914`". I can just manually archive them, but I think I would forget sometimes and then nobody else would have an archive, and then the version would be lost forever/until someone who stopped playing Roblox with the version on their computer comes back and finds it on their computer and uploads it online.
So, is there a way to do this automatically? I've tried using 7-zip with batch files and Task Scheduler and I got stuck trying to figure out what command to use.

---

Also, the 2 archives I have saved are around 200mb each, and I have 774gb of free space left on Drive D: and if my calculations are correct, I can fit around 3870 Roblox version archives in there. And Roblox updates once every 3-4 days, so it would take around 11610 days for Drive D: to fill up with archives. I'm not worried about my storage space.

Comment: In hurry , I wrongly assumed you wanted to copy files , not folders. I have updated my answer to copy folders. Hope it works now ! You should use `/K /O /X` to retain Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enough DiskSpace , thus zipping is not necessary & simple copying will do.

`COPY` : use to copy files
`XCOPY` : use to copy whole folders

Have a simple batch script which does this:
`DIR C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\`
`XCOPY /E /V /C /H /K /O /X /Y /J C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\* D:\roblox-archives\`
`DIR D:\roblox-archives\`

Meaning:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\* IS SOURCE , using wildcard to match the ever changing folder name  
D:\roblox-archives\ IS DESTINATION (make sure it exists)  
DIR on the SOURCE to see what new content is available  
DIR on the DESTINATION to see what content has been archived till now  

XCOPY OPTIONS :  
  /E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones
  /V           Verifies the size of each new file  
  /C           Continues copying even if errors occur  
  /H           Copies hidden and system files also  
  /K           Copies attributes  
  /O           Copies file ownership and ACL information  
  /X           Copies file audit settings  
  /Y           Suppresses prompting  
  /J           Copies using unbuffered I/O. Recommended for very large files
```

Initially, go to a CMD Prompt, and execute this bat script. Ensure that it works. When you are satisfied with the selected necessary flags, you can can re-run it , to ensure it works even when re-copying , that is , when SOURCE already exists on DESTINATION.

With all these checks going through , you can move on to automating it:
Put this script in `task Scheduler` to execute once a Day. Done.

Once in a while, you can have a look into `D:\roblox-archives\` & maybe make a zip file every month or so, by selecting all and making new zip file.

Comment: When I run the .bat script, it just makes a window appear and then it immediately disappears. I then tried running it in vs code with the CodeRunner extension, and it gave me this error:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\*
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.     
I did edit the script a bit, it's now:
COPY /Y C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\* "D:\MYREALNAME\File History\Roblox Version Archive"     
but it didn't work. By the way, all mentions of USERNAME in this comment were changed to my username, so that wasn't the problem.

Comment: In hurry , I wrongly assumed you wanted to copy files , not folders. I have updated my answer to copy folders. Hope it works now ! You should use `/K /O /X` to retain Properties.

Comment: This new script causes a new error, "Access denied". But I made my own answer that I made by looking up your old script, and then I spent around 2 hours trying to figure out what flags to use. Then I got the same error, and removed /X and /O. Doing that removed the error. Other than that, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Nice to know that ! About the "Access Denied" : that will occur in a corner case but you should execute the bat script with "Admin Privileges" to workaround that. In case you do not require all the file attributes in the archive, then you can avoid /X & /O ; If the file attributes are necessary, then use /X & /O along with "Admin Privileges" !! If all working fine, then no need to tweak it more !!

Comment: At first, I didn't know how to do that, but then I figured out you were talking about the "Run with highest privileges" option on Task Scheduler. But there is one more thing I want, is it possible to make the script only copy the files from the source if they are older than the ones in the destination? I tried /D, but that just makes it copy the files from the source if it is newer than the one in the destination. I just want this because it is possible to change the Roblox files through the Versions folder, and I don't want my changed files to be saved to an archive.

Comment: (Continuing from previous comment because I didn't have enough space) Roblox recently changed the death sound from the iconic "Oof!" to this really bad "Teh!". I want to change it back to the "Oof!" sound effect, but then if I do that and the task runs, the copy will have the "Oof!" sound effect, instead of the "Teh!" sound effect. I'm sorry if I'm asking too much for you, it feels like a lot of questions to me. Also, the admin privileges thing worked, thanks for that!

Comment: There is no Issue with asking more Questions, but that should be EITHER to clarify the Existing Question & Answer OR in a new Post because it will be unconnected to this Post. This Answer makes sense for the given Question. I would suggest you make a new Post to ask a new Question with Details.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for your help, I will now make a new post.

Comment: This is the new Question https://superuser.com/questions/1734622/is-it-possible-to-make-xcopy-only-copy-the-files-from-a-source-if-they-are-older !

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Prem's answer and it gave me an error, so then I started looking around some more. I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062503/batch-bat-to-copy-folder-and-content-at-once) that was basically asking for how to make the script that Prem said work (`COPY /Y C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\* D:\roblox-archives\`), and there was [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062503/batch-bat-to-copy-folder-and-content-at-once/5062591#5062591) that kind of helped, but not that much. Then I saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062503/batch-bat-to-copy-folder-and-content-at-once/5062591#comment51800379_5062591) that had a script that worked and copied everything from `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions` to `D:\roblox-archives`. Now I'm just hoping that Task Scheduler will work, because my previous attempts at using Task Scheduler were bad and nothing worked for me.

---

The script was `xcopy [source] [destination] /E /H /C /R /Q /Y`.