# Is it possible to make XCOPY only copy the files from a source if they are older than the ones in the destination?

Tags: windows, batch, windows-11, gaming, xcopy

Is it possible to make a batch script only XCOPY the files from a source if they are older than the ones in the destination? I'm trying to archive Roblox versions. I tried /D, but that just makes it copy the files from the source if it is newer than the one in the destination. I just want this because it is possible to change the Roblox files through the Versions folder, and I don't want my changed files to be saved to an archive. Roblox recently changed the death sound from the iconic "Oof!" to this really bad "Teh!". I want to change it back to the "Oof!" sound effect, but then if I do that and the task runs, the copy will have the "Oof!" sound effect, instead of the "Teh!" sound effect. If you need more information, I made another post a few days ago, and I am continuing off of it. [Here's the post.](https://superuser.com/a/1734158/1692089) The script I am using is:

```
DIR C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\
XCOPY /E /V /C /H /K /Y /J /D /O /X C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\* "D:\REALNAME\File History\Roblox Version Archive"
DIR "D:\REALNAME\File History\Roblox Version Archive"
```

Flag meanings:

```
/E   Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones
/V   Verifies the size of each new file  
/C   Continues copying even if errors occur  
/H   Copies hidden and system files also  
/K   Copies attributes  
/Y   Suppresses prompting  
/J   Copies using unbuffered I/O. Recommended for very large files  
/D   Copies all Source files that are newer than existing Destination files.
/O   Copies file ownership and ACL information  
/X   Copies file audit settings
```

So my question is, is there a flag/script that disables overwriting if the source has a newer version than the destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either I am not getting your Question or you are mixing up many things !

**I am given these solutions because you are asking for it, but there are better ways to automate it but that requires additional knowledge of Environment & Programing Experience !**

**SCENARIO 1 with MANUAL SOLUTION** :

Let us say ROBLOX has a new version `V1.RANDOM` & it contains "Image1 Image2 Image3 Text1 Text2 SOUNDX"

This `V1.RANDOM` will not be in the archive Directory hence you have to copy all.
Later when you change SOUNDX to SOUNDY, **DO NOT** copy again because you already have the archive of `V1.RANDOM`.

Even later, ROBLOX has version `V2.RANDOM` & it contains "Image1 Image2 Image4 Text3 Text4 SOUNDX"
This `V2.RANDOM` will not be in the archive Directory hence you have to again copy all.
Later when you manually change `SOUNDX` to `SOUNDY`, **DO NOT** copy again because you already have the archive of `V2.RANDOM`.

In this Scenario, you should not run the BAT Script via task scheduler. You should it run it manually just before you update `SOUNDX` to `SOUNDY` & your archive will contain what you want !

SCENARIO 2 with AUTOMATIC SOLUTION:

Let us say, you want task scheduler to run but you do not want to copy new `SOUNDY` and want to copy only original `SOUNDX` to the archive.

This will work in that case:
When you manually change unwanted SOUNDX to SOUNDY , make a copy of SOUNDX & SOUNDY in (say) `D:\SOUNDS\SOUNDX` & `D:\SOUNDS\SOUNDY` which is a way to restore it when required.

Then update your BAT Script with some lines before & after the XCOPY line:

```
....
CD "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\*\PATH-TO-FOLDER-CONTAINING-SOUNDX" ## USE WILDCARD * in CD COMMAND !  
COPY /Y D:\SOUNDS\SOUNDX <<SOUND-FILE-NAME>>  ## PUT BACK original unwanted SOUNDX before XCOPY  
XCOPY ....  
COPY /Y D:\SOUNDS\SOUNDY <<SOUND-FILE-NAME>  ## PUT BACK wanted SOUNDY after XCOPY  
CD "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Roblox\Versions\" ## come out of ROBLOX DIRECTORY  
....
```

This will work, but in case you run into Difficulties with folder names or file names, let me know & we can work it out.

Comment: Not gonna lie, I never even thought about the manual solution. Thanks for reminding me about it! I don't really feel like using the automated solution, because it looks like even more work. Thank you.

Comment: Nice to know that you got something useful out of this Answer !! That was the reason for including Automatic Solution & Manual Solution !!